# Call multiple services of a web service using AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, web-services, soap, android-asynctask, ksoap

I'm using Android Studio and when using kSOAP2 and some code i can call a service of a web service by creating a class that extends AsyncTask, my problem is how to use multiple services call while using AsyncTask, must i create a class that extends AsyncTask for each time i want to use a service? How to do that or how to use multiple services without using AsyncTask?

My example code:

*onCreate method:

```
String TAG = "Response";
Button bt;
EditText nom;
String getNom;
SoapPrimitive resultString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
    nom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nom);


    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            getNom = nom.getText().toString();
            AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
            task.execute();
        }
    });
}
```

*AsyncCallWs class:

```
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
        loginByName();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Response : " + resultString.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

*The method call:

```
public void loginByName() {
    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/TestWS/services/ServiceImpl";
    String METHOD_LOGINPARNOM = "loginByName";
    String NAMESPACE = "http://com.testws";
    String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/TestWS/services/ServiceImpl";

    try {
        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_LOGINPARNOM);
        Request.addProperty("name", getNom);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
        resultString = (SoapPrimitive) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

        Log.i(TAG, "Result Nom: " + resultString);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't need each step to do anything to the UI you can literally just call the services one after the other inside doInBackground and save any info you need isnide the AsyncTask to pass between the services just as you can anywhere else and then at the end return from the method as usual

I think what you're looking for is:

```
  new AsyncTask<Void, Void, MyResult>() {  //this is called an anonymous class

        @Override
        protected MyResult doInBackground(Void... params) {
            MyResult result;
            loginByName(); //first service
            .... //anythign else
            result = getMyResultService(); //another imaginary service
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(MyResult result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //TODO: anything that needs UI thread
        }

    }.execute(); //Make the magic start
```

Comment: Thanks Nick for your answer, i'm a beginner in android development, what i must do is not to call the services one after the other, some services will be called in onCreate and some in other events like onClick, and all that without creating AsyncTask each time, hope you uunderstand me.